# Minor issue in search results CSS

Tags: bug

Go to search
Enter the word test (inside the search box)
Click the tab "Votes" to return the results by count of votes.

The image on the left has a small issue.  Could we use the mechanism that add's a K to represent 1000's?
For instance:

[image]

Instead of displaying this whole number 13059, could we just display 13k.

PS: Im on chrome (latest version, windows 7).

Comment: The symbols such as K, or M (for millions) is good enough for me, the extra digits or precision is not important.  Besides we aren't flying to mars or the moon anytime soon.